# mapDispatchToProps working, but dispatched action does not fire off in onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Pretty green to React and Redux still. I have been running in circles trying to solve this problem, so I'm breaking down and posting this question. I actually had this working yesterday, and now I can't figure out what I've done to skrew it up.

The issue is that the createUser() action in the onClick event of the RegistrationButton does not seem to be dispatching. The onClick function is firing, but createUser never fires off.

It's got to be something small. Thanks for taking a look.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "../../App.css";
import { nextStep, createUser } from "../../actions/registrationActions";

class RegistrationButton extends Component {
  render() {
    switch (this.props.step) {
      default:
      case 1:
      case 2:
        return (
          <button className="submit-reg-form-btn" onClick={this.props.nextStep}>
            Continue
          </button>
        );
      case 3:
        return (
          <button
            className="submit-reg-form-btn"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              this.props.createUser({
                username: this.props.username,
                email: this.props.email,
                password: this.props.password,
                name:
                  String(this.props.firstname) +
                  " " +
                  String(this.props.lastname),
                birthdate: this.props.birthdate,
                gender: this.props.gender,
                preferredGender: this.props.preferredGender,
                liability: Boolean(this.props.liability),
                bio: this.props.bio,
                role: this.props.role,
                karma: this.props.karma,
                mentalState: this.props.mentalState,
              });
            }}
          >
            Complete Registration
          </button>
        );
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { registration } = state;
  return {
    step: registration.registrationStep,
    firstname: registration.firstname,
    lastname: registration.lastname,
    username: registration.username,
    email: registration.email,
    password: registration.password,
    birthdate: registration.birthdate,
    gender: registration.gender,
    preferredGender: registration.preferredGender,
    liability: registration.liability,
    mentalState: registration.mentalState,
    role: registration.role,
    bio: registration.bio,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    nextStep: (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      dispatch(nextStep());
    },
    createUser: (user) => {
      dispatch(createUser(user));
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegistrationButton);
```

```
registrationActions.js

import axios from "axios";
import {
  SET_ERROR,
  REGISTRATION_SUCCESS,
  ...
} from "./types";

export const createUser = (user) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.post("/api/createUser", user).then((res) => {
    if (res.data.error !== "") {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERROR,
        payload: "failed to create user",
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTRATION_SUCCESS,
      });
    }
  });
};
....
....
```

```
registrationReducer.js

import {
  SHOW_REGISTRATION_STEP_1,
  SHOW_REGISTRATION_STEP_2,
  SHOW_REGISTRATION_STEP_3,
  NEXT_REGISTRATION_STEP,
  REGISTRATION_SUCCESS,
  SET_FIRST_NAME,
  SET_LAST_NAME,
  SET_USERNAME,
  SET_USER_EMAIL,
  SET_USER_PASSWORD,
  SET_USER_BIRTHDATE,
  SET_USER_GENDER,
  SET_PREFERRED_GENDER,
  SET_USER_LIABILITY,
  SET_USER_MENTAL_STATE,
  SET_USER_ROLE,
  SET_USER_BIO,
  SET_ERROR,
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  registrationStep: 1,
  error: "",
  registrationComplete: false,
  firstname: "",
  lastname: "",
  username: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  birthdate: "",
  gender: "",
  preferredGender: "",
  liability: "",
  mentalState: "",
  role: "",
  bio: "",
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_REGISTRATION_STEP_1:
      return {
        ...state,
        registrationStep: 1,
      };
    case SHOW_REGISTRATION_STEP_2:
      return {
        ...state,
        registrationStep: 2,
      };
    case SHOW_REGISTRATION_STEP_3:
      return {
        ...state,
        registrationStep: 3,
      };
    case REGISTRATION_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: "",
        registrationStep: 4,
        registrationComplete: true,
      };
    case SET_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    ...
    ...
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
}
```

```
reducers/index.js

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import errorReducer from "./errorReducer";
import registrationReducer from "./registrationReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  errors: errorReducer,
  registration: registrationReducer,
});

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that breaks your code

```
 onClick={this.props.createUser({
```

You are, in fact, calling the method when the component mounts. What you actually need to do is this

```
 onClick={() => this.props.createUser({
```

And you might not need to treat the "e.preventDefault()" event after that, neither.

LE (following updated question)
Use the

```
bindActionCreators
```

method from redux to wrap your action creators. final version could look like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
createUser,
nextStep,
}, dispatch)
```

Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: I tried this and same effect. Updated the question.

Comment: Well, you also need to bind the action creators to the actions.
So import the 'bindActionCreators' method from redux and wrap the object inside mapDispatchToProps with it, passing 'dispatch' as a second param. 
https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators

Answer (score 0):

To `onClick` property you should provide function itself, not calling her as you did

Right way is

```
onClick={() => this.props.createUser(
```

or

```
onClick={this.props.createUser.bind(null, yourParam)}
```

Comment: Tried this to same effect